# Enabled button with. a state variable in a blocbuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have a bloc which I use to upload images from the gallery. I then have a `TextField` where I enter text. And finally another bloc where I have a button. The button is used to submit the data to a server(image and text). My problem is enabling the button. My code for enabling is:

```
class ObservationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ObservationPageState createState() => _ObservationPageState();
}

class _ObservationPageState extends State<ObservationPage> {
  List<File> files = [];
  TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _taskNameController = TextEditingController();
  String taskName;

  List<String> _selectedUsers = [];
  bool _enabled = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        BlocProvider.of<ImageBloc>(context).add(DeleteAllImages(files: files));
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor:  Colors.grey[200],
          appBar: AppBar(
          
            centerTitle: true,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(
              color: RioColours.darkGrey,
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
            elevation: 0,
            title: Text('Observation',style:TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Column(children: [
                     AutoSizeText(
              'Make an Observation and assign to a colleague ',
              maxLines: 1,
              style: RioTextStyle.auditQuestion(context),
            ),
           
            SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    
                      AttachPhoto(),
                      SizedBox(height: 20,),
                
                    BlocBuilder<ImageBloc, ImageState>(builder: (context, state) {
                      if (state is ImageInitial) {
                        return Container();
                      }
                      if (state is ImageLoadInProgress) {
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                      if (state is ImageLoadSuccess) {
                        //print(state.files);
                        files = state.files;

                        return SizedBox(
                          //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.5,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              itemCount: state.files.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, item) {
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10.0),
                                  child: ImageContainer(context: context, file: state.files[item]),
                                );
                              }),
                        );
                      }
                       if (state is NoImages) {
                      return Container();
                    }
                      if (state is ImageLoadFailure) {
                        return Container();
                      }
                      return Container();
                    })
                  ]),
                  Text(
                    'Notes',
                    style: RioTextStyle.auditHeaders(context),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height:10
                  ),
                   SizedBox(height: 140,
                                        child: TextField(
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        maxLines: 5,
                      controller: _descriptionController,
                      onChanged: (String value) {
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, height: 2.0, color: Colors.black),
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                         hintStyle: RioTextStyle.hintText(context),

                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300]),
                        
                        ),
                        hintText: "Enter your notes here"
                      ),
                  ),
                   ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .04,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Task Name',
                    style: RioTextStyle.auditHeaders(context),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10
                  ),
                  TextField(
                  
                    controller: _taskNameController,
                    onChanged: (String value) {
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, height: 2.0, color: Colors.black),
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      filled: true,
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),

                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300]),
                      ),
                      hintStyle: RioTextStyle.hintText(context),
                      hintText: "Enter your task name here"
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20
                  ),
                  
                 
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20
                  ),
                  BlocBuilder<ObservationBloc, ObservationState>(builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is UsersLoadInProgress) {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                    if (state is UsersLoadSuccess) {
                      final users = state.users;
                      return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
                        Text(
                          'Assign to',
                          style: RioTextStyle.auditHeaders(context),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .02,
                        ),
                        MultiSelectDialogField(
                          buttonIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,color: Colors.grey,),
                          chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                            chipColor: Colors.white,
                            textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                          onConfirm: (results) {
                            _selectedUsers.clear();
                            for (User user in results) {
                              _selectedUsers.add(user.id);
                              setState(() {
                                _enabled = true;
                              });
                            }
                            //  _selectedUsers = results;
                            print(_selectedUsers);
                          },
                          items: users.map((user) => MultiSelectItem<User>(user, user.first_name)).toList(),
                          title: Text(
                            'Assign Owners',
                            style: TextStyle(color: RioColours.splashBlue),
                          ),
                          cancelText: Text(
                            "CANCEL",
                            style: TextStyle(color: RioColours.splashBlue),
                          ),
                          confirmText: Text(
                            "ASSIGN",
                            style: TextStyle(color: RioColours.splashBlue),
                          ),
                          buttonText: Text(
                            "Choose Owners",
                            style: RioTextStyle.dropDownHint(context),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .05,
                        ),
                      ]);
                    }
                    if (state is UserLoadFailure) {
                      return Text('error');
                    }
                    return Container();
                  }),
                  BlocConsumer<ButtonBloc, ButtonState>(listener: (context, state) {
                    if (state is UploadFailure) {
                      RioHelpers.showFailureFlushBar(context, 'Error Uploading');

                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    }
                    if (state is UpLoadSuccess) {
                      _submit();
                    }
                  }, builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is Loading) {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                    if (state is ButtonInitial) {
                      print(_enabled);
                      return SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .07,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: (_descriptionController.text.isNotEmpty && _taskNameController.text.isNotEmpty && _enabled) ? () => callupLoad() : null,
                          color: RioColours.splashBlue,
                          child: Text(
                            'Submit',
                            style: RioTextStyle.buttonText(context),
                          ),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    if (state is UpLoadSuccess) {
                      BlocProvider.of<ImageBloc>(context).add(DeleteAllImages(files: files));

                      return SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .07,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: (_descriptionController.text.isNotEmpty && _taskNameController.text.isNotEmpty && _enabled) ? () => callupLoad() : null,
                          color: RioColours.splashBlue,
                          child: Text(
                            'Submit',
                            style: RioTextStyle.buttonText(context),
                          ),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    if (state is UploadFailure) {
                      return SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .07,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          //onPressed: (controller.text.isNotEmpty && _enabled) ? () => callupLoad() : null,
                          color: RioColours.splashBlue,
                          child: Text(
                            'Submit',
                          style: RioTextStyle.buttonText(context),
                          ),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    return Container(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                      height: 10,
                    );
                  }),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .12,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }

  callupLoad() {
    BlocProvider.of<ButtonBloc>(context).add(UploadTaskRequest(files: files, notes: _descriptionController.text, taskName: _taskNameController.text, owners: _selectedUsers));
  }

  _submit() async {
    print('called called called called called ');
    RioHelpers.showSuccessFlushBar(context, 'Observation recorded');
    BlocProvider.of<ImageBloc>(context).add(DeleteAllImages(files: files));
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    BlocProvider.of<ObservationBloc>(context).add(RequestUsers());
    super.initState();
    print("init calledx");
    _enabled = false;
  }
}
```

So the `_controller` works great for enabling/disabling the button. However `_enabled` which is a boolean state variable is my problem. In my `blocbuilder` I update my state to `_enabled= true` when the image upload is successful. However this is not making any difference to enabling the button. I've also updated the state variable using a `bloclistener` but that didn't work either.

How can I trigger the button to be enabled when I upload an image from the Gallery

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. What is is `_controller.text.isNotEmpty &&  && _enabled`? It doesn't compile.

Comment: sorry that should be `(_controller.text.isNotEmpty && _enabled)` that is my condition used to enable/disable button

Comment: There are many reasons why it's not working. Maybe hashcode/equals of state class implemented not right. Maybe something is wrong with your widget hierarchy, and so on and so forth. Provide more info so it would be possible to help. Provided code is difficult to understand. It looks like there is nothing wrong there.

Comment: here is the full code. Let me know if you spot anything!

Answer (score 0):

Set a local variable in the builder, not in the class itself, unless you want to use in another place. If you want to do so, wrap the variable assignment in a setState call.

Comment: you can't call setstate in a blocbuilder

Comment: But this is outside the context of the build method were you're changing your flag variable.

Comment: This means that you can call setState under a bloc listener callback.